# Predictions using Support Vector Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, prediction

In my problem there are four features(X); `a,b,c,d` and two dependents(Y); `e,f`. I have with me a data set containing a set of values for all these variables. How can I predict the values through Support Vector Regression using scikit learn in python, for the `e,f` variables when new `a,b,c,d` values are given?

I'm very new to ML and I would really appreciate some guidance since I found it very difficult to follow the scikit learn documentation on [SVR](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html).

This is what I have done so far with the help of an example in the sklearn documentation.

```
train = pd.read_csv('/Desktop/test.csv')
X = train.iloc[:, 4]
y = train.iloc[:, 4:5]

svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)
y_rbf = svr_rbf.fit(X, y).predict(X)

lw = 2
plt.scatter(X, y, color='darkorange', label='data')
plt.plot(X, y_rbf, color='navy', lw=lw, label='RBF model')
plt.xlabel('data')
plt.ylabel('target')
plt.title('Support Vector Regression')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This gives the error,

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
>   :
>   Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Fit or predict?

Comment: you want to predict `e and f ` at the same time e.g. new sample N has `e,f` = [0,1] or independently ??

Comment: Pandas indexing appears wrong here for your X variable - you are selecting a single column

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I changed it to select the correct columns.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that your target variables need to be independently predicted here, so correct me if I'm wrong. I've slightly modified the sklearn doc example to illustrate what you need to do. Please do consider scaling your data before performing the regression.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_samples, n_features = 10, 4 # your four features a,b,c,d are the n_features
np.random.seed(0)
y_e = np.random.randn(n_samples)
y_f = np.random.randn(n_samples)

# your input array should be formatted like this.
X = np.random.randn(n_samples, n_features)

#dummy parameters - use grid search etc to find best params
svr_rbf = svm.SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)
# Fit and predict for one target, do the same for the other
y_pred_e = svr_rbf.fit(X, y_e).predict(X)
```

Comment: @KrishiH Load that data from csv to the variables X and y and use this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data file has 6 columns, and the feature values are in the the first 4 columns, and the targets (which you call 'dependents') are in the final 2 columns, then I think you need to do this instead:

```
train = pd.read_csv('/Desktop/test.csv')
X = train.iloc[:, 0:3]
y = train.iloc[:, 4:5]
```